# Unexpected argument in constructing a subclass

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor, superclass

When constructing a subclass and using the constructor for the parent class, PyCharm points to an error in the super().**init**() line, stating that the last argument (base_growths) is unexpected. Here's an abbreviated version of the code:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, base_stats, base_growths):
        self.name = name
        self.stats = base_stats
        self.growths = base_growths


class Knight(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, base_stats, base_growths):
        super().__init__(self, name, base_stats, base_growths)

lancelot_bases = "placeholder"

lancelot_growths = "placeholder"

lancelot = Knight("Lancelot", lancelot_bases, lancelot_growths)
```

And here's the error I get when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\tests.py", line 16, in <module>
    lancelot = Knight("Lancelot", lancelot_bases, lancelot_growths)
  File "E:\Projects\tests.py", line 10, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, name, base_stats, base_growths)
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I'm not sure why it says I'm giving it five arguments. Though through testing, I've found that it's storing the name string in the base_stats variable, and the name variable is receiving

```
<__main__.Knight object at 0x0000029B854FBFA0>
```

I'm new to programming, so I don't know what that means, nor why it's happening. Please help.

Comment: Don't pass `self` to the super constructor.  Just `super().__init__(name, base_stats, base_growths)`

Comment: And if the `Knight` constructor does nothing but call its parents constructor without changing or re-arranging them, you can just leave out the entire `def __init__(....)`